# How to get a to JSP output a message from a class, after it outputs one from a servlet filter?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, message

I need to output a message to an account JSP which states if an account already exists or not (after users enter their username and password), but to the same JSP I have already output a message saying whether their inputs contain any certain characters or words (<, !, insert) etc.
I need these two outputs.
Is there a way to output two messages, one from two different servlets, to one JSP, one after another?
Is my second message even going to send if before the servlet containing it has ran, the JSP has already loaded and shown the first message?

Comment: Where is the check for certain characters or words? How are the filters setup? Are you trying to add a new filter or add it to an existing one?

Comment: The check for characters is in a servlet filter and the output of whether the account already exists is in a different servlet (create account) in the same src file. I already have them both setup, and without the servlet filter, the account JSP outputs the message from the create account servlet saying whether the account exists. But with the filter servlet it only outputs if banned characters have been input. I do not know how to get the two messages to output while the servlet filter runs